# Interpreting relations - are they functions?

Tags: functions, relations

I have two descriptions of two different relations and I need to determine whether they are functions. However, for some reason I have a really hard time interpreting what's going on here (esp. in (1)), maybe someone can help:

(1) $\{(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} | 7 | (b-a), -a -3 \leq b \leq -a +3\}$

(2) $\{(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} | b = |a|\}$

I'd be grateful for any tips and pointers!

Cheers!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You should choose your tags carefully. What has this to do with `linear-algebra`?

Comment: Oops, sorry, thanks I have changed it!

Comment: That condition $(b-a)/7$ makes no sense, since… well, it's not a condition. Are you sure it isn't $7\mid(b-a)$?

Comment: Yes, that could be a transcription error on my part, I'll edit it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, both of them are functions. That's easy to see in the second case: that's simply the function $a\mapsto|a|$.

The first one is the function $f\colon\Bbb Z\longrightarrow\Bbb Z$ defined by$$f(a)=\text{only element of }\{a-3,a-2,\ldots,a+3\}\text{ which is a multiple of }7.$$Note that this makes sense, since $\{a-3,a-2,\ldots,a+3\}$ consists of $7$ consecutive integers, and therefore it has one and only one multiple of $7$. And, with this definition, $7\mid\bigl(f(a)-a\bigr)$ and $a-3\leqslant f(a)\leqslant a+3$.

Comment: Thanks! Would the second case change, if I changed the order, e.g.: $\{(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} | a = |b| \}$

Comment: That's not a function, since both pairs $(1,1)$ and $(1,-1)$ belong to it. So, it is *not* true that, for each $a\in\Bbb Z$, there is one and only one $b\in\Bbb Z$ sach that the pair $(a,b)$ belongs to your set.

Comment: Thank you that's really helpful! So, if I was to rewrite this, it would be $f : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}, f(|a|) = b$ and therefore not each a has one b associated with it. Did I understand that correctly? But if I had $\{(b,a) \in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} | a = |b|\}$ that would again be a function because my input is the first of the tuple and my output the second?

Comment: Actually, the problem lies in the fact that for some $a$'s (actually, *every* $a\ne0$), there is more than one $b$ associated with it. In order that a relation is a function, there has to be one and only one such $b$.

Comment: But where in the notation does it specify which of the tuple is the one that has to always be unique? Because in my course we learned that a has to be unique always. So, how can I get from the notation $\{(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}\}$ to the knowledge which has to be the unique input to the function?

Comment: The notation has nothing to do with this . **By definition** a relation $R$ on a set $A$ is a function if, for each $a\in A$, there is one and only one $b\in A$ such that $a\mathrel Rb$. That's all. If you think that my answer did not answer your question, then just say so and I will delete it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116321/discussion-between-max-and-jose-carlos-santos).